# Scrollview is not scrolling

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, master-detail

I am using XCode's Master-Detail application with UISplitView. In my detailView, I have a scrollView. The scrollview works fine for iPhone, but refuses to scroll on iPad. The scrollViews has exactly the same settings in the iPad and iPhone XIB files. I am not using the storyboard.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: The ScrollView won't scroll if it has the same size as on an iPhone, because the iPad's screen is bigger. It's with the information you provided hard to tell how to solve it. Upload your project and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you yoeriboven. The scroll didn't work because of a spelling error, failing to connect the xib file. I didn1t see it because the simulator wasn't reset, and displayed an old file. All my bad. Thank you again for your offer and will to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [UIScrollView's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) `@property(nonatomic) CGSize contentSize` property. It defines if the scroll is needed.